# Azure subscription seems to be compromised

Tags: azure

I really need a help here. Overnight there were around 35 resource group created using my account and I am now in trouble trying to detach my credit card. The reason for that, is that I panickly disable the subscription then I removed all user roles appointed in my account. Now I am stuck with this spiral problem:  cannot detach credit card as there is still subscription exists > cannot activate subscription as I have no roles assigned.
Any suggestion what to do now?
I also cannot use help desk assistant as my subscription is disabled, however, the cost keeps incurring as there are still resource groups under my disabled subscription.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Contact the support of microsoft. 
There is a free 24/7 hotline and they can track which IP did what and when.
Dont worry and good luck.

Comment: @LenglBoy Thank you for replying. Can you please share the phone number, if you know one? I am trying to search it in websites, but I cannot find anything related to it. 
Thanks again.

Comment: It depends on your country/market (EMEA (eu)/ AMAP(usa) / CN (asia/china)).
You can also twitter them or use the forum.

Get more information here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/global-customer-service-phone-numbers-c0389ade-5640-e588-8b0e-28de8afeb3f2

Comment: Thanks @LenglBoy I have created a ticket and hopefully they will contact me asap. Twitter did not help much as they refer me to ticketing as well,